# Android alternative to iNetAddress or get it to use another resolver?

Tags: android, dns, ip, inetaddress

We have a situation in our office where the first DNS resolver found by Android doesn't work over wireless (intentional or not, not sure).  I'm doing an app to do whois lookups.  I need to translate the whois server to IP using the second resolver (I can run the properties, see the two resolvers, figure out which one works).  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, INetAddress only works on the first resolver.  Is there a known alternative, workaround, or anything I can use to get the IP address of a domain through a specified resolver?  Even dnsjava itself uses INetAddress.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dnsjava does not use `InetAdress.getByName()` or `InetAddress.getAllByName()`.

Just use it like this:

```
System.setProperty("dns.server", "<resolver you want to use>");
InetAddress addr = Address.getByName("<name>");
```